# Horizontal navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal navigation menu, but despite inserting the `display: inline`, the menu is still shown in a vertical matter.

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" data-useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>blivori.net - Web Design and Development</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Brian Livori's personal website. " />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma|Prosto+One|Maven+Pro:500,400|Playfair+Display+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carrois+Gothic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <header>
        <div class="header-container">  
        <div class="left-side-header">          
            <div id="logo">
                <h1>blivori.net</h1>
                <h2>{Web Design and Development}</h2>           
            </div>
        </div>  
            <div class="middle-header"></div>
            <div class="right-side-header">
                <div class="navmenu">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="AboutMe.html">About Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </header>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #eee; /* Fills the page */
}

/-------HEADER---------/

#logo {
    font-family: 'Michroma', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Prosto One', cursive;
    font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
}

#logo h1 {
    font-size: 32pt;
    line-height: 10%;
}

#logo h2 {
    font-size: 8pt;
    line-height: 0%;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.header-container {
    width: 80%;
    font-family: 'Michroma', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Prosto One', cursive;
    font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;  
}

.left-side-header {
    width: auto;;
    float: left:
}

.right-side-header {        
    width: auto;
    float: right;
}

.navmenu {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Carrois Gothic', sans-serif;
  display: inline; 
}

.navmenu A:link {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
.navmenu A:visited {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
.navmenu A:active {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
.navmenu A:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #66CCFF;}

.navmenu li:before {
    content: "+";   
    text-indent: -1em;  
}

.navmenu a {
    width:150px;
}

.navmenu ul {
 list-style: none;
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix this, and more importantly, why is it happening?

Comment: One note, you need to move all your page content within the body tag. Right now it's above it.

Comment: @j08691 Aren't content found in the header (logo, navmenu, etc) seperate from the body?

Comment: No, everything visibly on the page should be within the body.

Comment: No, all of it belongs in the body. Only the `<head>...</head>` content should be before the body. Also, I'm not seeing where you set the list item display to inline anywhere.

Comment: @j08691 it is found in `.navmenu {}`

Comment: .navmenu is a div several levels above the list items. Try applying the inline display to the list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this

```
.navmenu {
  display: inline;

}
```

You need to target the list items

```
.navmenu li {
  display: inline; /* I prefer inline-block though */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some options but the easiest is: `display: inline-block` the other can be `display: block` and you can `float: left`

Then you can even go indepth such as using table-cell and flex